# capture group in wildcard that may have specific order

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match any string that has `([a-zA-Z0-9$\s]*)` but I also want to match in that group an `=` and a `>` but only if they appear together like `=>`

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work `([a-zA-Z0-9$\s]|=>*)`

Is there a way to do this in one regex and possibly one capture group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just move your asterisk outside the brackets...

`([a-zA-Z0-9$\s]|=>)*`

add another pair of brackets to capture it all...

`(([a-zA-Z0-9$\s]|=>)*)`